# Is creating a variable to hold an object sometimes redundant?

Tags: java

I've seen this so many times:

```
public class MyApp extends SomeLibrary
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    MyApp app = new MyApp();
    app.run();
  }
}
```

Instead of:

```
MyApp app = new MyApp();
app.run();
```

Why not just do:

```
(new MyApp()).run();
```

when a) garbage collection exists, b) it's clear that nothing else is going to be run inside `public static void main`, and that c) `app` is clearly not going to be referenced again?

Comment: It's a personal preference. I use both depending on how well it reads, or how well my colleagues think it's reads, other than that, no different to a where you should put your opening {.

Comment: Sometimes it is desirable to have an object to inspect when you are debugging.

Answer (score 4):

- it does not make a difference (I suspect the bytecode might even be the same - EDIT: just checked: it's not)
- the first form is generally more readable
- the second makes sense when readability is not affected - typical example:

  ```
  new Thread(someRunnable).start();
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, if there is nothing more in your application, you can do it as

```
(new MyApp()).run();
```

But usually, applications are a little more complex and you assign your instance to a variable because you have initializations to do.

Answer (score 1):

Other than readability, there is no difference between the two ways: some IDEs actually suggest replacing the former with the latter.  I actually prefer `new MyApp().run();` myself.